# Is there a way to retrieve iTunes Persistent ID on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, persistent

looking for a consistent unique ID across all iPhones associated with a iTunes account. Seems that the iTunes persistent ID would be ideal, however unable to find out how to retrieve this from within my xCode application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information isn't available programmatically to an application.

Ask a broader question about what you're trying to accomplish and perhaps someone can offer more help.

Comment: Thank you. Basically we need an ID that is consistent for any device that is associated with a given iTunes account. This ID will be used as part of an encryption for certain assets. We want these assets accessible via any device associated with given account (ID used in decryption).

Comment: @Alan: There is unfortunately no reliable way to do this. If the assets are available via in-app purchase, there's a StoreKit mechanism for verifying nonconsumables that should do what you need. But if you're rolling your own, there's nothing you can do short of building your own registration system that ties users to the content.